# I tried to use ajax with Codeigniter but it didn't work for me

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I tried to use ajax and bootstrap with codeigniter after downloading them, I did a simple test but at the end I got nothing .

```html
<script src="<?php echo base_url()  ?>assets/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php echo base_url()  ?>assets/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#filiere').on('change' , function(){
  alert('cwork....');
});
  });
  </script>
```

can you please help me out

Comment: what ajax did you try?

Comment: If you want to receive love from Stackoverflow please follow this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: jQuery v2.2.4  note that am using codeigniter 3.1.8

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the `jQuery` library js file, that's why `Uncaught ReferenceError`error occurred,

if you want to you ajax, first you should add ajax library file. you can download it for here : https://jquery.com/download/ or you can use direct link.

Then you should start jquery function to load before making your ajax request

you should you like following,

```
<!-- jquery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="<?= base_url('assets/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/jquery.js'); ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('assets/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.js');?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#filiere').on('change', function(){
        alert('cwork....');

        // start ajax here
        /*$.ajax({

        });*/
    });
});
</script>
<button id="filiere">filiere</button>
```